# How can I determine the moment when an ImageView will move a certain distance from its original position

Tags: java, android

It's my first question here, sorry for the mistakes.

In my app I have an animated ImageView. If somebody click on it, it moves to random coordinates.
It is necessary that at the moment when the ImageView overcomes a certain distance (set initially) a Toast appears.
My problem is that the Toast appears many times regardless of whether the ImageView has covered a given distance or not.
Need your advice how can I fix it.
Thank you in advance!

```
private final int MAX_LENGTH = 420;
private int xRand, yRand;
private int xStart, yStart;

private View unlimitePlayView;
private ImageView circle;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   unlimitePlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tournament, container, false);
   circle = unlimitePlayView.findViewById(R.id.circle);

   circle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         xStart = (int) circle.getX();
         yStart = (int) circle.getY();
         xRand = new Random().nextInt(deviceWidth - circle.getWidth());
         yRand = new Random().nextInt(deviceHeight - circle.getHeight());

         Path path = new Path();
         path.moveTo(xStart, yStart);
         path.lineTo(xRand, yRand);

         animCircle = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(circle, "x", "y", path);
         animCircle.setDuration(1000);
         animCircle.start();

         animCircle.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
               float currentX = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("x");
               float currentY = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("y");
               int currentLength = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(currentX - xStart), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(currentY - yStart), 2));
               if (currentLength > MAX_LENGTH) {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well written question! It is because `currentLength > MAX_LENGTH` is true not only the first time. If it was true once, it will be true every call of `onAnimationUpdate()`.

Remember the toast was shown before and prevent it afterwards. For instance:

```
         animCircle.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            private boolean wasFired = false;
 
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
               float currentX = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("x");
               float currentY = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("y");
               int currentLength = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(currentX - xStart, 2) + Math.pow(currentY - yStart, 2));
               if (currentLength > MAX_LENGTH && !wasFired) {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  wasFired = true;
               }
            }
         }
```

Another small improvement: I removed `abs()`, since the square of a negative number is always positive.